# Not working Angular 10 Edit Route in URL?

Tags: javascript, angular10

working with Angular 10 project and I have employee-edit page in employee-edit folder. and My app.module.ts like this,

```
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { EmployeesComponent } from './components/employees/employees.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { EmployeeEditComponent } from './components/employee-edit/employee-edit.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component:EmployeesComponent},
  {path: 'edit/:id', component:EmployeeEditComponent}
]
```

and link to the Edit page is like this?

```
<td><button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm mx-2" routerLink="edit/{{ emp.id }}">Edit</button>
```

but when I type following url `localhost:4200/edit` edit-employee page is not working here. not error encounting it is redirecting to `localhost:4200` page again how could I fix this problem here?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Please share more details - for example, where did you define the route `edit` without any further parameters?

Comment: what did you mean? I need more understanding